# capture the return url of submitted form in android webview

Tags: php, android, forms, webview

I'm trying to submit a form in a remote url that I loaded in my webview. whenever I submit it, the php script reads it and runs it, but when it sends back the request it sends a url which then prompts me to view it using a browser.

Is there a way for android to capture that url so that it wont run on a web browser, but instead run it on my android application?

I am creating a hybrid app which is why I can't use phonegap since I will be using some native app features.

This is my current syntax:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.com/");
```

my php script does is it reads the form(its a login form) then process the login and session variables, and then sends back the url it needs to access the other webpage, I have not used any php framework.

What can I do capture the Url being sent by the php script? Do I need to create a condition so I could send 2 different commands for both my web and android application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a new WebViewClient and override shouldOverrideUrlLoading method. This will be called for all url's you call:

```
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            //do whatever you want with url
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });
```

If your request is a redirect and it's on API level < 10 you might want to call onPageStarted instead.

```
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            //do whatever you want with url
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

```
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `<data>` element as part of an intent filter as outlined [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)

So for example:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mywebsite.com" />
    ...
</intent-filter>
```

I think the action is `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />` but I'm not 100% sure.